# Error: Cannot send request to server. node php-fpm localhost

Tags: php, node.js, pubnub, fpm

fpm library. I  want to integrate pubnub and replace socket io with it, but my code does not work in localhost.

**What i have done till now**

i have followed [this](http://www.sintesisdigital.com.mx/dashboard/docs/use-php-fcgi.pdf) to install fpm in xampp. Did i miss something? what i can do to run it?

after  installing it worked for once but again stopped working (did not change anything in code).

the code works fine on live server.but in localhost i am getting below error.

**Stripped content to Error: Cannot send request to server. but found something wrong...**
see below image

[image: ![enter image description here]

**This is my code**

```
"use strict";

var PHPFPM = require('node-phpfpm');
var striptags = require('striptags');
const log = require('simple-node-logger').createSimpleFileLogger(process.env.LOGDIR + '/poker-phpwrapper.log');

class PHPWrapper {

    constructor(concierge) {
        this.phpfpm = new PHPFPM({
            host: process.env.NODE_POKER_PHP_HOST,
            post: process.env.NODE_POKER_PHP_PORT,
            documentRoot: process.env.NODE_POKER_PHP_DOCROOT
        });

        this.concierge = concierge;
        this.busy = false;
    }

    houseKeeping(messages) {
        var php = this;
        php.busy = true;
        this.phpfpm.run({
            uri: 'server_wrapper.php',
            json: {
                func: "houseKeeping",
                messages: messages
            }
        }, function (err, body, phpErrors) {
            php.busy = false;
            if (body.trim() == '') {
                return;
            }            
            // Check for PHP errors
            if (body.includes('<br />')) {
                // Get all the errors out until we've just got JSON left
                body = body.substring(body.indexOf('\n[')+1);
            }
            
            if (body.charAt(0) != '[') {
                console.log('Stripped content to ' + body + " but found something wrong...");
            }
            
            try {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
            } catch (parseError) {
                // throw("An error occurred parsing the JSON from PHP: " + parseError + "\nBody contents:\n" + body);
                data = '';
            }
            if (data.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            for (var i in data) {
                if (data[i][0] == 'CONTROL') {
                    // Server control message, execute as appropriate
                    switch (data[i][1]) {
                        case 'force_exit': php.concierge.wipeStateAndExit(); break;
                        case 'reset_server': php.concierge.wipeState(); break;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Message for client
                    php.concierge.msgToClient(data[i][0], data[i][1]);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    isBusy() {
        return this.busy;
    }

}

module.exports = PHPWrapper;
```